# How to count number of rows in a sas table using x command

Tags: unix, sas

Does anyone know how to count number of rows in a SAS table using x command, I need to achieve this through unix. I tried `wc -l` but it gave me a different result than what proc sql `count(*)` gives me.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean. Please describe the problem more in detail and add an context, so that people can think about other strategies to tackle it.

Comment: use x command to start sas batch script that will proc sql count(*)

Comment: To use the `X` command you need to be running SAS.  So just use SAS code to count the number of OBSERVATIONS in the DATASET.

Answer (score 1):

Lee has got the right idea here - SAS datasets are stored in a proprietary binary format, in which line breaks are not necessarily row separators, so you cannot use tools like `wc` to get an accurate row count. Using SAS itself is one option, or you could potentially use other tools like the python `pandas.read_sas` module to load the table if you don't have SAS installed on your unix server.

Writing a script to do this for you is outside the scope of this answer, so have a go at writing one yourself and post a more specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks, this explains why wc and sql count (*) have different results. I'd give the python code a go.